# reused UITableViewCell with KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing

A tableview with reused UITableViewCell, Every cell has its own Label. This Label is which I defined, a subclass of UILabel. The label display a string. And the string is changed depend on a NSMutableDictionary. In label class, I am using KVO to addObserver. When the key's value change in NSMutableDictionary, The label will receive this change and change the display value. The problem is when the NSMutableDictionary removeAllObjects. most label in cell display with "-.-",That is right. But only a few cell's label display previous value, That is not right. It seems because of the tableviewcells reused, it occures this bug.

```
Tableview Class:

//Add Observer

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// Add Observer
   NSDictionary* dic = [_paramters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   if (!dic || dic.count <= 0) {
     return;
   }

  NSString* key = [dic.allKeys objectAtIndex:0];
  if (!key || key.length <= 0) {
    return;
  }

   ParameterTableViewCell* paramCell = (ParameterTableViewCell*)cell;
   //Add Observer
   paramCell.valueLabel.paramKey = key;
}

// Remove Observer
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  ParameterTableViewCell* paramCell = (ParameterTableViewCell*)cell;
  //Remove Observer
  [paramCell.valueLabel removeKeyObserver:paramCell.valueLabel.paramKey];
}

Label Class
- (void)setParamKey:(NSString *)paramKey{
  if (![_paramKey isEqualToString:paramKey]) {
    [[CnogaCurveManager sharedCurveManager] addParameterValueObserver:self forParameterKey:paramKey];
    _paramKey = paramKey;
  }
}

- (void)removeKeyObserver:(NSString*)paramKey{
 [[CnogaCurveManager sharedCurveManager] removeParameterValueObserver:self forParameterKey:paramKey];
}

- (void)dealloc{
 [[CnogaCurveManager sharedCurveManager] removeParameterValueObserver:self forParameterKey:_paramKey];
}


//This is where I change label's value
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context{
if([_paramKey isEqualToString:keyPath]){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
        self.text = [[CnogaCurveManager sharedCurveManager] paramterValueForKey:keyPath];
        if (!self.text){
            self.text = @"-.-";
        }
    });
 }
}

CnogaCurveManager Class

- (void)addParameterValueObserver:(NSObject*)observer forParameterKey:(NSString*)parameterKey{
try {
    if(![NSString stringIsEmpty:parameterKey]){
        if ([self.obeseverKeys containsObject:parameterKey]) {
            return;
        }

        [self.parameterMeasurement addObserver:observer forKeyPath:parameterKey options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
        [self.obeseverKeys addObject:parameterKey];
       }
} catch (NSException *exception) {

}

}

- (void)removeParameterValueObserver:(NSObject*)observer forParameterKey:(NSString*)parameterKey{
try {
    if(![NSString stringIsEmpty:parameterKey]){
        if (![self.obeseverKeys containsObject:parameterKey]) {
            return;
        }

        [self.parameterMeasurement removeObserver:observer forKeyPath:parameterKey];
        [self.obeseverKeys removeObject:parameterKey];
    }
} catch (NSException *exception) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right when saying the problem come from reused cell.

When you call `removeAllObjects` on `dic`, `key` will be `nil` and it makes `tableView:willDisplayCell:` returns before setting `paramCell.valueLabel.paramKey` again. That's why you see a few cell display previous value.

To fix it, reset `valueLabel.paramKey` when a cell is reused by using [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse?language=objc) method. Put below code in your `ParameterTableViewCell` class

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.valueLabel.paramKey = @"";
}
```

Comment: thank you for your kindly response, but it does not resolve my problem.

Comment: Can you add tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: Do you have skype account? Could I contract you? Thank you very much